# MsAccess Free text in dropdown

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables tied by a foreign key. Example:

> Customer -> CustomerType

I've created a form where I have a dropdown for each customer. Dropdown contains all customer types. Now, sometimes person who enters data wants to add new customer type to that customer without leaving the form. is there a way to have a free text input in dropdown and automatically creating a record in the db if it does not exist? or is there a way of having "new..." option which will expose textbox to enter new group name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dropdown is a combo box, use its *On Not In List* event.  Allen Browne has sample code you can adapt: [Option 1: Not In List event](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-27.html#NotInList)

If your dropdown is a list box, I don't know how to do it without opening another form.

Comment: Did you even try looking at the Help file for the NotInList event? It explains how to do this, completely with code examples.

Answer (score 0):

If the user types-in the new categorie in the combobox it will save this new customer type in the customer table but not in the customerType table.

What you could do is:

1. have a onchange event that check for the "add a new customerType" row being selected
2. have a form open in modal view to add the new cutomerType (form properties PopUp = true and Modal = true)

\

```
Private Sub province_Change()
 If Me.comboBoxCustomerType.SelText = "Add a new customerType" Then
  DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAddNewCustomerType"     
 End If
End Sub
```